# I click on a category, but the filter based on title of the category, is not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a page wherein my sidebar, I list all the categories that I have in my database, it is showing as in the image,

[image]

It is showing based on my database, as shown below,

[image]

And this is my code for the category,

```
<?php
include('db.php');

   $r = mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT * FROM category order by title asc");

   if($r) {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
         echo '<a href="category.php?filter='.$row['title'].'" class="list-group-item">'.$row['title'].'</a>';
      }
   }
?>
```

The problem is, why when I click at the category, it is showing me an error page?

[image]

Do I have to include any other code or else? Help me please, thank you. 
**I KNOW MY CODES ARE VULNERABLE, JUST IGNORE IT**

Comment: Show us your code so we can help it out

Comment: Please do check the **url** if it is correct, and that `category.php` exists. Is that really suppose to be `shop/shop/`?

Comment: looks like it has to be `shop/shop/admin` , let me check that first @CarlBinalla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Warning: Don't use such code if sql vulnerabilities can happen. This
>   doesnt offers or any practice to use such code. This is just mere
>   answer to users question.

```
<?php
    include('db.php');

    //if query string exists, fetch it from url
    if(!empty($_GET['filter']))
    {
      $filter = $_GET['filter'];
      $r = mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT * FROM category WHERE title='$filter' order by title asc");

       if($r) {
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
             echo '<a href="category.php?filter='.$row['title'].'" class="list-group-item">'.$row['title'].'</a>';
          }
       }
    }
    else
    {
         $r = mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT * FROM category order by title asc");

       if($r) 
       {
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
             echo '<a href="category.php?filter='.$row['title'].'" class="list-group-item">'.$row['title'].'</a>';
        }
       }
    }
    ?>
```

Also when I was checking the URL, please check shop/shop/ url is coming, is that proper?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.